# Which practice is better to manage the project repo/workspace & why?

Tags: express, devops, mern

**Strategies- I have a project, divided into three-part**

1. Landing page (example.com, main domain). I`ll use Next js
2. dashboard pages (app.example.com, subdomain). I`ll use Next.js
3. backend (api.example.com, subdomain). I`ll use Node, Express, MongoDB

What will be good practice to set up the project base and repository..?

Example #1- I can create three separate repo and manage and deploy them individually. (Suitable for me)

Example #2- I can create two GitHub repo- landing page + dashboard(not sure I can manage them within the single repo. their route and subdomain will be different) and backend
Example #3- I can create a single GitHub repo and manage them all together (It seems difficult for me)

What do you do in your project?
Thanks for your time.
Zelal